# Estimate frequency based on given sample

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, sample, frequency

I have a list of users (~25 million) and a dataset containing events created by the users in a specific time window (eg all tweets of all Twitter users that happened in a month - on avg I have 100K events/day).

I want to calculate the frequency that a user creates an event (or how frequently a user posts a tweet).

Is there a way to estimate the true frequency that a user tweets, given that there are many users that never tweet and other that tweet rarely and probably do not have a single tweet in the sample?

Comment: Your last para (beginning) is vague. you may indicate for which category  you want an estimate.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar what do you mean? There is only the event creation date and the user id. There are no categories

Comment: many users that never tweet and other that tweet rarely